# Using snprintf to print restricted hex value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char buff[255];
    snprintf(buff, 255, "%02x", 0xFFFFFF);
    printf("%s\n", buff);
}
```

I am expecting the above code to print `ff`(since I gave %02x) but the op is `fffff`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your expectations are wrong.

From [the manual page for the `*printf()` family](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> In no case does a nonexistent or small field width cause truncation of a field; if the result of a conversion is wider than the field width, the field is expanded to contain the conversion result.

You can truncate strings using the precision ("`.N`") modifier, but not using field width:

```
printf("%2s and %.2s", "foo", "foo");
```

prints

```
foo and fo
```

You can't use precision to truncate integers.

Comment: to clarify , this is for integers; you can actualy truncate strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a binary mask, change:

```
snprintf(buff, 255, "%02x", 0xFFFFFF);
```

to

```
snprintf(buff, 255, "%02x", 0xFFFFFF & 0x0000FF);
```

E.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) /* main() is not valid */
{
    char buff[255];
    snprintf(buff, 255, "%02x", 0x00BEEF & 0x0000FF);
    printf("%s\n", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ef
```

Comment: Is there a difference between printing the lowest byte of a little endian integer vs. a big endian one?

Comment: @Jongware, no difference, but I don't know if OP wants to print the end of `0xAABBCC` as a string (`0xCC`) or as a number (`0xCC` on little endian, `0xAA` on big endian).

Comment: That is indeed unclear, the OP might as well have used `char buff[255] = "ff";`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Unwind’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26232109/1741125) says, you can only pass a minimum, not a maximum field-width to `*printf` for integer conversions.

As long as you only convert an integer per call, you can use the size argument to `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(buff, 3, "%02x", 0x9abcdef);
```

Output (with the otherwise unchanged code):

```
9a
```

I changed the number being converted to illustrate the difference to masking, `0x9abcdef & 0xff` is `0xef` and masking with `0xff000000` (the highest-order bytes of a 4-byte integer) yields `0x9`. I don't know of an easier way to get the two highest-order non-zero nibbles (0-padded on the left if they don’t exist).